# No Volume Group found error.How to rebuild initrd in Red Hat 5.1?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Motherboard failed in one of the Red Hat Server. So, I moved the HDD to a new box. As If I boot the machine. This error shows up. After refering to many sites, they said about rebuilding initrd.
So, How can I do it? Will it resolve the problem? or something else needed?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when changing motherboards due to the lack of appropriate drivers in the initial RAM disk image.

To resolve it try following:

- Boot from a RedHat installation disc and type `linux rescue`.
- Mount all filesystems in read-write mode.
- chroot to your filesystem.

  `mount --bind /proc /mnt/sysimage/proc`

  `mount --bind /dev /mnt/sysimage/dev`

  `mount --bind /sys /mnt/sysimage/sys`

  `chroot /mnt/sysimage`
- Create a backup of your current initrd

  `cp -p /boot/initrd-$(uname -r).img /boot/initrd-$(uname -r).img.bak`
- Create initrd for the current kernel

  `mkinitrd -f -v /boot/initrd-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)`
- OR, if you need to build it for a specific kernel version (change version according to your setup)

  `mkinitrd -f -v /boot/initrd-2.6.18-371.6.1.el5.img 2.6.18-371.6.1.el5`
- reboot

Hope this helps!

Deeh